# Maven won't use public key to deploy

Tags: java, maven-2, ssh, public-key

I'm using SSH to deploy my Java artifacts to a server. I have the keys set up so that I can interactively SSH to the server without requiring a password, but when I try to run the "`mvn deploy`" or "`mvn release:perform`" commands, it hangs (at what I assume is the password prompt).

My `~/.m2/settings.xml` file contains the username for the server (because it is different than my local username) and references the `id` of the server that requires the different user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you sure your `settings.xml` provides everything required? Did you declare your `privateKey` (and the `passphrase` if necessary)? Something like this:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>server001</id>
      <username>my_login</username>
      <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
      <passphrase>some_passphrase</passphrase> <!-- if required -->
      <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
      <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
      <configuration></configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```

Comment: I needed the <passphrase/> element. This is pretty darn disappointing! Why won't it read the passphrase from my Ubuntu keychain just like mvn does?

Answer (score 5):

In your distributionManagement section, try using "scpexe://" in your url instead of "scp://".

This calls the standard scp program (assuming it is on your path), instead of using the Java implementation of scp that is built into Maven. Standard scp uses ssh-agent (which, in Ubuntu, starts automatically when you log in through GDM) for public-key auth.

Comment: You also need to use `wagon-ssh-external` in that case.