# How do I get the Maven Release Plugin to work with Git over SSH?

Tags: git, maven, ssh, cygwin

I'm trying to use the Maven Release plugin with git over ssh.
I run the command **mvn release:prepare** and get the following error:

```
[INFO] Working directory: C:\projects\sample
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push ssh://bill@hbox/sample master:master"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\projects\sample
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4:prepare (default-cli) on project sample: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Permission denied, please try again.
[ERROR] Permission denied, please try again.
[ERROR] Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
[ERROR] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have the following in my pom.xml:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://hbox/sample</developerConnection>
    <tag>sample-1.1</tag>
</scm>
```

I'm using public key authentication to access the ssh server, and the command  **ssh bill@hbox**  works without prompting for a password.  Apparently the maven release plugin is not picking up my private keys, and i can tell because it is executing a series of "cmd.exe"'s to run git.  **So where am I supposed to put my private key, and how do I let Maven know about it?**  I've looked at the documentation for the Maven Release plugin, and I saw nothing in the config about ssh keys.  I added a new server element to my settings.xml file, but this didn't work either.  Any documentation that you can point me to on this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Other notes: The private key isn't protected with a password.  Also, I'm on Windows 7 and cygwin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796303/maven-wont-use-public-key-to-deploy

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here. I couldn't get the maven release plugin to work under cygwin, but it will work if you use msysgit (open git-cmd.bat) and then enter the command "echo %HOME%", and then put id_rsa in %HOME/.ssh.

[MSysGit and ssh config. missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122439/msysgit-and-ssh-config-missing)

Comment: this resolved problem for me of MSysGit/SSH not finding the "id_rsa" key